# How to return Array of two JSON Object in Jersey RESTFul API(JAX-RS)

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey-2.0, restful-authentication

I have designed login module in RESTFul API using jersey.

whenever any error occurred while login it will return error code and message like,

```
{
  "errorFlag": 1,
  "errorMessage": "Login Failed"
}
```

but whenever I get successful results it returns

```
{
  "apiKey": "3942328b-fa65-496c-bf32-910aafbc1b0e",
  "email": "caXXXX@gmail.inl",
  "name": "Chandrakant"
}
```

I'm looking for results like below

```
    {
          "errorFlag": 0,
          "errorMessage":{
          "apiKey": "3942328b-fa65-496c-bf32-910aafbc1b0e",
          "email": "caXXXX@gmail.inl",
          "name": "Chandrakant"}
 }
```

Comment: I don't really understand the point of having something other than an error message in the field named "errorMessage", but anyway, what is your question? What prevents you from doing it? How do you plan to store the API key and the name of the user if the authentication failed, and you thus don't know who the user is?

Comment: See updated question, client app will check whether flag is 1 or 0

Comment: I still don't understand the point of having something other than an error message in the field named "errorMessage". And you still haven't told what your question was, and what prevented you from doing it. But why would you do that anyway? The client should already know that it's a success because you send back a response with a 2xx status (typically 200 - OK). And it should know that it's an error because you send back a response with an error status (here, it should be 401). That's the standard HTTP way of doing things, and all client HTTP librraies rely on these standard ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use structure like below,

```
{
  status/statusCode :  200/400, //eg. 200 for success, any other for failure.
  statusMessage : "Success/<failureMessage>",
  errorDetails : "Failed due to <reason>"   //optional
  data :{    //data will exists only in case of success call.
  }
}
```

you can achieve this like below,

```
@GET
@Path("/images/{image}")
@Produces("image/*")
public Response getImage(@PathParam("image") String image) {
  File f = new File(image);
 
  if (!f.exists()) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(404);
  }
 
  String mt = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
  return Response.ok(f, mt).build();
}
```

Comment: This make sense, but how can I achieve this, any code samples

Comment: Use the above classes `Response` class, go through the docs and you will find how to build your own response..

Answer (score 0):

You can return all the attributes in HashMap as key value .
Below piece of code worked for me

@POST
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public HashMap check(InputStream  inputJsonObj) {
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put("key1", "value1");
        return  map;
    }